# exim forward possible alliass error or duplicate?

Tags: email, forward, exim, exim4

I don't know how to formulate this more clear..
Sorry for that.

The forwarding works like a charm. Except in the following scenario:

I want to forward info@domain1.nl to info@domain1.com
(domain names are the same except they each have another extension)
So when i do this the mail gets 2 times in the mailbox of info@domein1.nl instead of delivering one copy to info@domain1.com.

Now when i check the mainlog in exim(i use 4.76) it tries to forward to the alias 'info'..
If i say this correctly the alias of `info@domain1.nl` is `info` **BUT** the alias of `info@domain1.com` is also `info`.

Is this possible, and how can i resolve this?

ps. not that much of a exim expert, but really want to solve this :(
I am now forced to redirect this using another email adres with a filter to send all the emails to the right mail..

Comment: Edit your post to include the output of 'exim -bt info@domain1.nl info@domain1.com info'.  I suspect we'll find something in that output that will explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is quite dumb :$

@Todd, still thanks for commenting..
But the problem wasn't exim or and forwarder at all!
I used a domain pointer on domain1.nl..
And the domain pointer was domain2.nl.
So i removed the domain pointer and changed back the forwarders and everything worked fine..

Ahh well, at least everything is working..

**EDIT:** Can't except my own answer within 2 days.. so sorry will do it than.